# Create a assistant multi step

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I created a assistant to configure a device, each step makes an entry in the corresponding table in the database. So far so good. The problem that I consider is, if the most efficient way, because when I cancel the assistant, the data still stored are not deleted, and do not want this to happen, I want the assistant is canceled, these data are not stored, or are removed. Someone tells me the right way to create an efficient assistant? Thanks greetings.

Thanks greetings.

Comment: Instead save data on each step, save it to session, and on last step only make flush.

Comment: as I can keep the objects in session in symfony? Thank you

Comment: No object, just form data entered by user, but if you really want entities in session, you can serialize them.

Comment: Save the form sent in a session variable?
Could you give me an example? Thank you

Comment: something like `$data = $form->getData(); $request->getSession()->set('serialized_form', json_encode($data));` ?

Comment: Check the code of this bundle to get idea, or use it: https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle